# Large static map in program memory Java

Tags: java, android, memory, collections, dictionary

I am translating 16-bit codes from a legacy device into strings as defined by a table.  There are over 2,000 codes, and the codes are not consecutive.

They are currently defined in a HashMap like this...

```
public class SomeActivity {
    private static final Map<Integer, String> myMap;
    static {
        Map<Integer, String> aMap = ...;
        aMap.put(0x2345, "this");
        aMap.put(0xFEA3, "that");
        ...
        myMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(aMap);
    }
}
```

This is being ported for android, and I am concerned about how much RAM this will use up on a device.  Can I do something similar, but stored in program memory?

Comment: can't you use a properties file?

Comment: @user503413 could you provide an example?

Comment: What do you think "program memory" is if it's not RAM? Have you actually tested this to see if it's a problem? (It's not going to take *that* much memory for 2000 map entries.)

Comment: Have you tested with only one element, then with all 2 thousands of them, watch the size in Eclipse's profiler

Comment: A quick ballpark calculation using 64 bytes per map entry gives 128KB for the map of 2000 entries. Not an issue, for example a *single* fullscreen bitmap on the *lowest* resolution low-end Android device is like *twice* as big.

Comment: I will profile and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `SparseArray` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html) would be more suitable than a basic HashMap.

You could also put that in a Property file (see http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Properties.html) that you put in the assets of your program (you still have to load all the file in memory to read 1 value)

You can even pre-make an sqlite database out of it and copy it from your assets (see http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/). In this case, the values are in file, and only required elements are loaded.

However, I wouldn't worry about 2000 items in RAM unless your strings are very long.

Answer (score 2):

The codes may not be consecutive, but if they're fairly dense (i.e. the likelihood a number between `min(keys)` and `max(keys)` exists is high, say over 75%) you might be able to save some space by pre-constructing a `String[]` object of size `max(keys)-min(keys)` and using it like a map.

If it's available / an option for Android development, another excellent alternative for primitive maps and other data structures is the [Trove library](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/) which can similarly save you a lot of space and time when working with primitive data structures.

Alternatively, since you call `Collections.unmodifiableMap()` consider Guava's [`ImmutableMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html) - it's not as efficient as Trove, which avoids auto-boxing primitives, but it is more memory efficient than Java's standard HashMap ([though slightly slower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756940/guava-immutablemap-noticably-slower-access-than-hashmap)).

That said, like the comments suggest, you may very well be worrying about nothing.  As always, "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."  It's quite likely a simple Java HashMap will serve you just fine.